# when is a moment matrix singular?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with finite moments and consider the moment matrix $M_{i,j} := E[X^{i+j}]$, $0\leq i,j <n$. Is it true that $M$ is singular if and only if there exist $\alpha_i$, $i=0,\ldots,n-1$, not all equal to zero, such that $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha_i X^i = 0$ with probability 1?

(In the case I am considering, $X$ is discrete and $E[X]=0$.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $M_{i,j} = E[f_i(X) f_j(X)]$ with arbitrary functions $f_1,\ldots, f_n$.
If $M$ is singular, then there exists $\alpha \in R^n$, $\alpha\neq 0$, such that
$\alpha^T M \alpha = 0$. But this means $E[ (\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i(X))^2] = 0$, which means $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i(X)=0$ with probability 1. The converse is obvious.